# Is $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sec^2(x)\,dx \neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

I have had a discussion with my classmates recently, and an answer on the 2016 Calculus BC AP test said that:
$$\int_0^\pi \sec^2x = \infty$$
The problem I am having is that we can split this and write it as a limit.
$$\int_0^\pi \sec^2x\,dx = \lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \biggl(\int_0^b \sec^2 x \,dx + \int_b^\pi \sec^2 x \,dx\biggl)$$
Therefore:
$$\int_0^\pi \sec^2x = \lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \biggl(\tan(b) - \tan(0) + \tan(\pi) - \tan(b)\biggl)$$
$$= \lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \biggl(\tan(b) - \tan(b)\biggl)$$
$$= \lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \biggl({\sin(b) - \sin(b) \over \cos(b)}\biggl) = {0\over0}$$
Using L'Hopital's Theorem:
$$\lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \biggl({\sin(b) - \sin(b) \over \cos(b)}\biggl) = \lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \biggl({\cos(b)-\cos(b)\over{-\sin(b)}}\biggl)$$
Evaluating:
$$\int_0^\pi \sec^2x\,dx = {0-0\over{-1}} = 0$$
I must have made a mistake, but I just don't know where my logical fault is.  Any answers would be much appreciated.
Edit: I knew the work was wrong, just not how.  Thanks for the answers!

Comment: $tan(b)-tan(0)+tan(\pi)-tan(b) = tan(\pi) - tan(0)$

Comment: But $tan(\pi) - tan(0) = 0$.  I was simplifying to show that the answer was zero, and the previous AP test has a different answer...

Comment: Independent of any arguments about impropriety and the fundamental theorem. If that integral makes any sense at all it must be greater than $0$ since the integrand nonnegative everywhere and positive most of the time. So the only question is whether limiting arguments show it's finite, hence positive, or undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in the very first line where you claim that
$$\int_0^\pi \sec^2x\,dx = \color{red}{\lim_{b\to{\pi\over2}} \left(\int_0^b \sec^2x\,dx + \int_b^\pi \sec^2x\,dx\right)}.$$

This is not true because the two improper integrals must be set up as **separate** limits:
$$\int_0^\pi \sec^2x\,dx = \lim_{b_1\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}}\left(\int_0^{b_1} \sec^2x\,dx\right) + \lim_{b_2\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{+}}\left(\int_{b_2}^\pi \sec^2x\,dx\right).$$

Those $b_1$ and $b_2$ are, technically speaking, different things (even if we denote them with the same letter $b$, as people often do). Neither limit, i.e. neither improper integral, converges. For example, for the first one:
$$\lim_{b_1\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}}\left(\int_0^{b_1} \sec^2x\,dx\right) = \lim_{b_1\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}}\left(\left.\tan x\right|_0^{b_1}\right) = \lim_{b_1\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}}\left(\tan b_1 -\tan0\right) = \lim_{b_1\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}}\left(\tan b_1\right) = +\infty.$$
Similarly, the other one diverges to $+\infty$ too.

Now, we're entering a little bit of a grey area. On the one hand, we can **not** add limits, because the limit property that you implicitly applied in your very first incorrect step:
$$\lim(A+B)=\lim A+\lim B,$$
is conditional — it's only true when both limits on the right-hand side exist. In other words, we can only add limits when we know that those limits are numbers, but we can't add non-numbers.

… Or can't we? Since both integrals diverge to $+\infty$, and we are adding them, we can say that the total also goes to $+\infty$. (Note that subtracting infinities, on the other hand, is a no-no!) Still, since infinity is not a number, saying that this improper integral *diverges*, i.e. that this limit *doesn't exist*, is the right answer.

Comment: Actually it's correct to say that $\int_0^\pi=\lim_{b\to\pi/2}(\int_0^b+\int_b^\pi)$, simply because $\int_0^b+\int_b^\pi=\int_0^\pi$ for all $b$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, it's correct -- but absolutely irrelevant to the discussion at hand. It's true that $\int_0^b+\int_b^\pi=\int_0^\pi$. But depending on the value of $b$, one of these integrals is improper. For example, if $b>\pi/2$, then $\int_0^b\sec^2x\,dx$ is improper with a singularity at $\pi/2$ inside the interval. So we'll have to split this one as $\int_0^b=\int_0^{\pi/2}+\int_{\pi/2}^b$, and treat each one as a limit: $\int_0^{\pi/2}=\lim_{c\to\pi/2^-}\int_0^c$ and $\int_{\pi/2}^b=\lim_{c\to\pi/2^+}\int_c^b$. So we end up doing the same thing as I explained in my answer anyway.

Comment: I didn't claim it was relevant. If it's correct but irrelevant then you should't say that that's where the error is. The error is in evaluating both the subintegrals using FTC.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Oh, okay, I see you point now. You're right -- going by what the OP wrote, that is the mistake. But I was going by what he meant -- and I am sure that he was trying to reproduce the standard textbook approach to improper integrals, but he did that a bit incorrectly. So I guess we're both right but in different ways. :-)

Answer (score 6):

If $b<\pi/2$, then $\int_b^\pi \sec^2x\,dx$ is undefined. If  $b>\pi/2$, then $\int_0^b \sec^2x\,dx$ is undefined. There is no value of $b$ such that

$\int_0^b \sec^2 x\, dx + \int_b^\pi \sec^2 x\, dx = \tan(b) - \tan(0) + \tan(\pi) - \tan(b)$

is valid.

Your work is just a fancy way of claiming that $\int_0^\pi \sec^2x\,dx = \tan(\pi) - \tan(0).$

Note if you were to take $\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon} \sec^2 x\, dx + \int_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^\pi \sec^2 x\, dx$

and then look at what happens when $\epsilon$ approaches 0 from the right, you should get infinity. There are other cases where you get positive infinity for one integral and negative infinity for the other, and the temptation is to cancel them out, but that is not valid. Infinity minus infinity is undefined.

Comment: That was not my claim.  I simply claimed that the value was zero, not that it was derived from the FTC.

Comment: @DanielGarner: But in this example you can't simplify "$\tan(b)-\tan(0)+\tan(\pi)-\tan(b)=\tan(\pi)-\tan(0)$" simply because you do **NOT**  have "$\tan(b)-\tan(0)+\tan(\pi)-\tan(b)$". Those $b$'s are different things and can't possibly be equal to each other, so they do **NOT** cancel out. And the reason they can't be the same is, as this answer pointed out, because one is less and one is greater than $\pi/2$. So a more correct expression at that step is $\tan(b_1)-\tan(0)+\tan(\pi)-\tan(b_2)$.

Comment: @zipirovich No, the $b$'s _can_ be the same - it's true that $\int_0^\pi$ = $\int_0^b+\int_b^\pi$. The problem is that there's an error in his evaluation of one of the two pieces; either $\tan(b)-\tan(0)$ or $\tan(\pi)-\tan(b)$ is wrong, which one depending on $b$.

Comment: @DanielGarner You use FTC twice, once when saying $\int_0^b=\tan(b)-\tan(0)$ and once when saying $\int_b^\pi=\tan(\pi)-\tan(b)$. One of those applications of FTC is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If $b>\pi/2$ then $\int_0^b\sec^2(\theta)\,d\theta=\infty$, not $\tan(b)-\tan(0)$. (The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus does not apply since $\tan$ is not differentiable on $(0,b)$.) Similarly with the other part if $b<\pi/2$.

Comment: I know that the FTC is unappliable, but does that mean that if you use a limit as I have, you still can't apply it?

Comment: @DanielGarner If $b>\pi/2$ then your evaluation of $\int_0^b\sec^2$ is simply wrong. This has nothing to do with whether you're taking a limit later.

Comment: Oh, so the limit, because you approach from a side, must be applicable from both sides.  I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielGarner No, that's not really the problem. You could just take a one-sided limit. If yyou take the limit as $b$ decreases to $\pi/2$ then your evaluation of $\int_0^b$ is wrong, while if you take the limit as $b$ increases to $\pi/2$ then your evaluation of $\int_b^\pi$ is wrong.

Comment: @DanielGarner The error really has nothing to do with that limit. Honest.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of a positive integrand cannot be zero. That settles the question in the title.

---

The reason why you find a zero value is because you are integrating across a singularity, and this may not be done without care.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to sketch or visualise the integral to see what you're doing wrong. It's like claiming $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^2}=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5huto3izhk) that $\infty$ is indeed the correct evaluation.
Also, as seen in the graph, $\sec^2(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is undefined, and this will throw off your integral.